# Texture rendering incorrect on a parcticle in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

So, I tried to do a pile of blueberries and something went wrong

I was using particle system with molecular addon

Textures are looking right in texture view
[image]

But when rendered

[image]
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

The root of the problem was bad lighting and roughness at 0.2 in BSDF shader...[image]